# InternetCrackUrl not returning lpszHostName properly

Tags: c++, winapi, url, dll, nsis

I am developing a plugin for NSIS (Unicode) and I am trying to use InternetCrackUrl() to get the hostname of a URL (ie: http://www.google.com/test.html -> www.google.com) but instead of lpszHostName just returning "www.google.com", it returns "www.google.com/test.html".

Here is my code:

```
void __declspec(dllexport) Example(HWND hwndParent, int string_size, TCHAR *variables, stack_t **stacktop, extra_parameters *extra) {
    g_hwndParent=hwndParent;

    EXDLL_INIT();

    LPWSTR szURI = new WCHAR[string_size];
    URL_COMPONENTS urlComp;

    // Sets szURI to "http://www.xyz.com/test.html"
    popstring(szURI);

    wstring strUri = szURI;

    ZeroMemory(&urlComp, sizeof(urlComp));
    urlComp.dwStructSize = sizeof(urlComp);

    // Set required component lengths to non-zero so that they are cracked.
    urlComp.dwHostNameLength = static_cast<DWORD>(-1);
    urlComp.dwSchemeLength = static_cast<DWORD>(-1);
    urlComp.dwUrlPathLength = static_cast<DWORD>(-1);
    urlComp.dwExtraInfoLength = static_cast<DWORD>(-1);

    if (!InternetCrackUrlW(strUri.c_str(), strUri.length(), 0, &urlComp)) {
        return _T("InternetCrackUrl failed");
    }

    // urlComp.lpszHostName = www.xyz.com/test.html
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What about returning a substring from the beginning of strUri until first backslash?

Comment: That's what I did. Here's the code:

    wstring strHost = urlComp.lpszHostName;
    strHost = strHost.substr(0, strHost.find_first_of('/'));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't provide your own buffer InternetCrackUrl will return pointers to characters in the original string you pass as input. It doesn't copy the string.

So, lpszHostName will point to the first character, and dwHostNameLength will give you the number of chars that make the host name.

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior.
Because when you say www.google.com it translates to http://www.google.com/test.html.
The URL is really www.google.com/test.html which is what is returned.
To get what you need, you will need to do some string manipulation.

You could use the strrchr function or the find_first_of method of the std::string class.

Comment: The whole point of InternetCrackUrl() is that it does this for you.